# Integrating Office 365 Calendar with Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, office-365, icalendar

I am trying to integrate a [offiche-365](/questions/tagged/offiche-365) calendar to [google-calendar](/questions/tagged/google-calendar). The purpose is to use the [ical](/questions/tagged/ical) from the `google calendar` in a 3rd party app where I can only read Google Calendars.

However, what shows up in my app is only the original Google Calendar, with no events from the integrated Office 365 calendar showing up.

What should I do to make the integrated `O365 calendar` to show up as part of the Google Calendar ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is something you would like to achieve but I have started using the Flow app. First I have defined a new calendar in Google Calendar. Next I have opened the Flow app and defined new flow based on one of the provided templates (called like "Synchronize/Create new events from Office 365 Calendar on Google Calendar" or something similar).

Next, you need only to choose the calendar from your Google account where the events should be synchronized to.

It works for me for last 6 months and is great.

Hope that helps.